# MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using ULTIMANG Template, it works fine locally but when I upload it on Github and clone the code from there it gives me

MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
error.

I am using Angular 9 and i have face that error first time. Please someone guide me how to fix that.
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170 May be you can follow this as there is a similar discussion here.

Comment: i had followed that but its didn't solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

add command in your angular project for sass watch.

Open package.jason in script add "scss": "sass --watch src/assets:src/assets --no-source-map"

this will generate css file for sass and compile them, you will find the file which will be causing error then you can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is useful while using Nodejs.

create public folder in root directory
then create css folder inside public folder here you create your own css file.
then add following line of code to your app.js file

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

then add following path to your css link href of html file.

"css/filename.css"

Hence problem solved. This solution worked for above problem (100%)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).